# Using select inside insert query with preparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to write an insert query using **preparedStatement**. Inside it I want to put a selection query. I did the following but I get: You have an error in your SQL syntax

```
protected final String createStudentQuery = " INSERT INTO student (student_id, ed_level) VALUES (SELECT MAX(user_id) FROM user WHERE usertype ='Student' , ?)";
```

and then

```
stmt5 = conn.prepareStatement(createStudentQuery);
stmt5.setString(1, ed_level);
stmt5.executeUpdate();
```

All the declarations(connection, statement) have been made.

Comment: Have you tried executing this update manually (putting an appropriate string in place of the `?`)?

Comment: @dcsohl yep. Does not work

Comment: So then the Java code is kind of irrelevant, no? You may want to see if a `SELECT` can be used inside of the `VALUES` clause as you are doing. What did the database tell you when you executed it manually?

Comment: @Reimeus the java code is to indicate that I am indeed replacing the ? in the preparedStatement as I should. It kept saying You have an error in your SQL syntax. It doesn't like the `select MAX(user_id) from user where usertype = 'Student' , test)`.

Comment: @Reimeus lol now you have a parentheses missing. But let me try putting the select inside ()

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 values that needs to be inserted, student_id and ed_level . But in your select statement there is only one value, MAX(user_id). You have to also add the value for ed_level in the select query.

Also, your query should be:

```
INSERT INTO <TABLE_1> (COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2,...) SELECT COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2,... FROM <TABLE_2> WHERE <CONDITION>
```

I have modified the query to something like this:

```
INSERT INTO student (student_id, ed_level) VALUES ((SELECT MAX(user_id) FROM user WHERE usertype ='Student') , ?)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but you aren't using preparedStatement. Furthermore , I am giving two values by using the setString and replacing the ?

Comment: I am trying to do `INSERT INTO (column1, column2) values (?, ?)`. Dont get confused by the select query. It just replaces the first ?